# How do you make a javascript popup like the ones on AllTop.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make simple javascript popups like the ones on alltop.com (when you hover over the links). Is there a jQuery plugin for this?

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "jQuery tooltip", there exist plenty.

http://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+tooltip

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a ton of jQuery plugins for this.  One of my favorites is [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

Answer (score 1):

It's called "tip" :) .. There are several plugins that could be useful to you.

I.e. :

- http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin
- http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/